# Instance member 'showSettings' cannot be used on type 'SettingsLauncher'

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to move a whole pile of code in my button to a single file.
Here's the button in my original VC

```
    let blackView = UIView()
    let settingsLuancher = SettingsLauncher()

    @IBAction func refreshBtnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

      SettingsLauncher.showSettings()

    }
```

And here is the SettingsLauncher.swift,

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class SettingsLauncher:NSObject {

let blackView = UIView()

func showSettings() {
    if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow{
        blackView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)
        window.addSubview(blackView)
        blackView.frame = window.frame
        blackView.alpha = 0

        blackView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDismiss)))

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
            self.blackView.alpha = 1
        })
    }

}

func handleDismiss(){
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
        self.blackView.alpha = 0
        // dismisses blackView
    })
}
```

The compile keeps failing and it's showing: 
**Instance member 'showSettings' cannot be used on type 'SettingsLauncher'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?**

Not sure why this happened, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using class name `SettingsLauncher`, instead on object `settingsLuancher`:

```
SettingsLauncher.showSettings()
```

should be

```
settingsLuancher.showSettings()
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at `SettingsLauncher.showSettings()` it's not class method it instance method so It will be called by instance of class not class itself.

like below

```
settingsLuancher.showSettings()
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question! Unfortunately, I can only choose one answer, but your solution is very much appreciated!